# »Werden« mit Vermutungen

Tags: grammaticality, tense, future, grammar-identification

Ich bereite mich auf die B2-Prüfung vor und habe einen Satz in meinem Arbeitsbuch gelesen:

> Frau XYZ wird verschlafen haben.

Ist das nicht gegen die Regeln?

*Wird*, *verschlafen* und *haben*: 3 Verben?
Oder habe ich etwas übersehen?

Comment: Same as in English: ...will have done...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Du hast es hier mit einem Satz in der Zeitform [Futur 2](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Tempora/Futur2.html) zu tun.

Diese Zeitform wird gebildet aus der konjugierten Form von *werden*, gefolgt von der jeweiligen (nicht konjugierten) Perfekt-Form des Verbs. Da letztere selbst aus *haben* oder *sein* und dem Perfekt-Partizip besteht, gibt es im Futur 2 tatsächlich drei Verben.

Diese Zeitform drückt entweder eine Vermutung über etwas schon geschehenes aus, oder (in Verbindung mit einer Zeitangabe) eine Erwartung über den Ausgang eines Geschehens in der Zukunft.

> Wo ist Frau Müller? Sie müsste längst hier sein! - Sie wird verschlafen haben.
> Morgen um diese Zeit wirst Du Deine Prüfung hoffentlich bestanden haben.